# Weird div block

Tags: html

I have a question about this: https://gyazo.com/1851299f16c3148c81f8e83682d38ff1
https://gyazo.com/05adf6012ba98bbae93ecda4dabbdffa

It can be a stupid question or just a stupid code. But how can i get that long block away? My logo is scaled and correct. But if i delete that long div block, then the logo unscaled, and be big.

Need advice.
Thankyou!

Comment: can you post your html and css? I am on a large monitor and can barely see that code.

Comment: @mlegg I posted links to 3 fiddles containing the code.

Comment: @JordanWagner it is up to the poster of the question to include what they have tried and a code sample

Answer (score 0):

I created a few examples on jsfiddle for you.

**1)**
To get rid of the black bar you could do something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="Logo">
      <img class="LogoNav" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/9front_logo.svg/150px-9front_logo.svg.png">
    </div>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Over</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bestellen</a></li>
</div>
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/x4912b7s/1/

**2)**
To move the links to the right of the logo, but still inside the black box:

```
.LogoNav {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/x4912b7s/2/

**3)** To remove the black box and move the links next to the logo:

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="Logo">
      <img class="LogoNav" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/9front_logo.svg/150px-9front_logo.svg.png">
    </div>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Over</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bestellen</a></li>
  </div>
```

css

```
.LogoNav {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/x4912b7s/3/

Hopefully this helps.